# Can I do this (MOSFET instead of switch)?

Tags: mosfet, switches

This might be a very trivial question: Can I simple swap a switch that is connected to a RESET pin with internal pull-up with a N-channel MOSFET?

My goal is to pull the RESET to ground using a signal (OUTPUT) instead of a switch, but not sure if it is this simple?

So can I replace this:

[image: circuit with switch]

with this?:

[image: circuit with N-channel MOSFET]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, that's ok. Make sure to put a pull down on the gate of the MOSFET.

Comment: Got to be careful to get a MOSFET with a low gate threshold, particularly if using 3.3 volt logic.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTrbAh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Elaborated a little bit, you still have the button and a `RESET#` signal.

Comment: Overly complex, and doesn't do what the OP wants since there's no control input and RESET output (or input - bidirectional signal anyway).

Comment: @Majenko this isn't really "overly complex", he's just showing what's effectively on either end of the circuit, in the ICs (another dashed line around the HC04 buffer would be nice though). The only problem I see is that if the reset line is driven low, the switch will short the power. It would be better if the switch is connected between the drain and ground.

Comment: Thanks, for the elaboration. But I'm okay with taking the switch totally out. I do wonder though why you drew the HC04 in. What's the function here of a signal inverter? (I don't really understand what @Nick T means with the dashed line part)

Comment: @Ruben The I actually just threw the `74HC1G04` in as some sort of representation of being output of another gate.